# Gunicorn has more than one thread despite --thread 1

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn

I don't really understand up to now, how gunicorn works. What I currently see is, that if I start:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn -k eventlet --timeout 60 --log-level debug --workers=1 -b 0.0.0.0:5001 flaskVideoClient2:create_app(5001,10)
```

and than run

```
ps -aux | grep flaskVideo
```

I get this response

```
user  0.0  0.0  13464  1096 pts/14   S+   10:33   0:00 grep --color=auto flaskVideo
user 13684  0.0  0.4  95624 34796 pts/7    S+   10:20   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn -k eventlet --timeout 60 --log-level debug --workers=1 -b 0.0.0.0:5001 flaskVideoClient2:create_app(5001,10)
user 13698  0.4  0.5 199228 45696 pts/7    S+   10:20   0:03 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn -k eventlet --timeout 60 --log-level debug --workers=1 -b 0.0.0.0:5001 flaskVideoClient2:create_app(5001,10)
```

so it seems, that there is running more than one thread.

How do I have to interpretate the two running threads?

Comment: `ps -aef --forest` were they started independently or do they share a common process?

Comment: Ok, it seems, that the second one is child of first one. But what does it mean,m since there are running two threads. Or is the parent no longer actively serving?